# Taking oracle database dump via c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, oracle10g

I have a very interesting problem.

I use Process.Start with the "runas" verb to run a process as administrator ie.

```
string currentstatus;
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            Process myprocess = new Process();
            try
            {
                startInfo.FileName = "cmd"; //
                startInfo.Verb = "runas";
                startInfo.Arguments = "/env /user:" + "Administrator" + " cmd";
                startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                startInfo.UseShellExecute = false; //'required to redirect
                startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; // '<---- creates no window, obviously
                myprocess.StartInfo = startInfo; //
                myprocess.Start(); //
                System.IO.StreamReader SR;
                System.IO.StreamWriter SW;
                Thread.Sleep(200);
                SR = myprocess.StandardOutput;
                SW = myprocess.StandardInput;
                SW.WriteLine(commandexecuted); // 'the command you wish to run.....
                SW.WriteLine("exit"); // 'exits command prompt window
                Thread.Sleep(200);
                currentstatus = SR.ReadToEnd();

                SW.Close();
                SR.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            { }
```

Which said to have command executed is given as

```
exp *****/******@!!!!!!! owner =!!!!!!!! file =D:/SS.dmp
```

now my problem is

1) when i run the above query manually by right clicking the cmd.exe and choose "Run as administrator " it works fine  but with out it it throws me the error

2) so i need to execute that process through code.

i do not know where i went wrong?

is this only the way to take oracle dump or else it might be having some other way?

waiting for your valuable response and comments.....

updated 1)

I too use this code to check whether the current user is administrator or not  through

```
    private static bool IsAdministrator()
{
    WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
    WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);
    return principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
}
```

it returned me as the current user is only a administrator.

any sugessions for my above problem !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since runas was useless, try embedding an [application manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx)

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

That should work, anyway you always have the handy:

```
myprocess.StartInfo.UserName = "Administrator"; 
myprocess.StartInfo.Password = "password";
```

Comment: thanks for your response i checked it already but i did not understand can you help me regarding it

Comment: with out getting admin username and password is this possible ?

Comment: @GowthamanSS Sure, see the last point of the link provided. 1. Use a text editor, such as Windows Notepad, to create a default manifest file, temp.manifest. 2. Use mt.exe to insert the manifest.  The command would be: mt.exe –manifest temp.manifest –outputresource:YourApp.exe;#1.

Comment: i am getting error code as Error : Error reading Win32 manifest file 'D:\***\*******\mt.exe -manifest "$(ProjectDir)$(TargetName).exe.manifest" -updateresource:"$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).exe;#1"' -- 'The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. '

Comment: @GowthamanSS What happend when you burn the user and password and try to run without right click and run as admin?